# Почему в SQL запросе значение передаваемое в WHERE интерпретируется как название колонки?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, mariadb

Есть пользователь с логином dude. Хочу получить его id из БД SQL-запросом:

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=" . $_SESSION["login"]);
```

Выдаются ошибки:
**Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dude'  in 'where clause'**
**PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'dude' in 'where clause'**

**Вопрос: что не так и как это исправить?**

Comment: А что в ` $_SESSION["login"]` находится? Вообще, посмотрите весь sql. Интересно, а если в `login` передавать, например `"1 or dude=1"`, то сработает инъекция и это вызовет эту же ошибку? :) По хорошему, нужно запрос с параметрами (binding) оформлять -- https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @gil9red а ну да, надо через prepared передавать, логин же пользователь вводит, я забыл)

Comment: @gil9red а по поводу ошибки у Вас есть предположения в чем дело?

Comment: Думаю, в логине было такое, из-за чего логин стал частью выражения, пример такого я в комменте выше писал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему в SQL запросе значение передаваемое в WHERE интерпретируется как название колонки?

Потому, что в SQL в принципе в выражении любой токен, не являющийся корректным литералом, переменной или функцией воспринимается как имя столбца.

Строковые литералы должны быть заключены в кавычки.

> как это исправить?

Обернуть в кавычки.

Чтобы не морочиться с экранированием внутренних кавычек и не запоминать в каких СУБД какие кавычки есть специальная функция [PDO::quote](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.quote.php)

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login=" . $pdo->quote($_SESSION["login"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно переменную `$_SESSION["login"]` засунуть в переменную `$seslog` и в sql запросе в кавычки заключить эту переменную:
`$seslog = $_SESSION["login"]; $result = $pdo->query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login= '$seslog'");`
Должно все сработать, а если такого логина нет, то просто пустота будет, без ошибок.

Comment: @JustLearn …, а если в логин каким-то образом попадет `'` то запрос посыпется, а если это будет сделано намеренно и грамотно, то получите инъекцию. Обязательно экранируйте все, что попадает в запрос